# LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role despite using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I declared @Transactional but still got the error failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:    fa.training.model.KhachHang.suDungMay, could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Specifically: in the AllCustomerInfoController class, I'm looking to get a list of all customers that use SuDungMay and SuDungDichVu:

```
@Controller
public class AllCustomerInfoController {

    @Autowired
    private KhachHangRepository khachHangRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    @Transactional
    public String allCustomerInfo(Model model) {
        List<KhachHang> listKhachHang = khachHangRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listAllCustomer", listKhachHang);
        return "allcustomerinfo";
    }
}
```

My Entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class KhachHang {

    @Id
    private String maKh;
    private String tenKh;
    private String diaChi;
    private String sdt;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "khachHang")
    private List<SuDungMay> suDungMay;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "khachHang")
    private List<SuDungDichVu> suDungDichVu;
}

@Entity
public class SuDungDichVu {
    @Valid
    @EmbeddedId
    private SuDungDichVuId suDungDichVuId;
    private int soLuong;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "maKh")
    @MapsId(value = "maKh")
    private KhachHang khachHang;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "maDv")
    @MapsId(value = "maDv")
    private DichVu dichVu;
}

@Entity
public class SuDungMay {
    @EmbeddedId
    @Valid
    private SuDungMayId suDungMayId;
    private double thoiGianSd;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "maKh")
    @MapsId(value = "maKh")
    private KhachHang khachHang;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "maMay")
    @MapsId(value = "maMay")
    private May may;
}
```

How to get the customer list containing the list SuDungMay and SuDungDichVu without lazy error, thanks!`

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not working even with @Transactional because all you do is to add the reference of your entities to a model and return. Your transaction gets closed and your objects are accessed afterwards when constructing the View. In your case you need to fetch eagerly or map to a Dto inside `allCustomerInfo` this way it should work.